# Spring select tag outside form tag

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to bind Spring select tag which is located outside form tag. In plain HTML it was done by "form" attribute. Is it possible to do the same with Spring tags?
I have something like this in my jsp:

```
<div>
    <form:form ...>
        <form:input.../>
        <form:input.../>
    </form:form>
</div>
<div>
    <form:select...>
        <form:options .../>
    </form:select>
</div>
```

Comment: By *"form" attribute"*, do you mean `#form` macro?

Comment: in plain html a did it like this: <select ... form="formid"></select>